# How to identify a user during Basecamp oauth api authorization?

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, basecamp

So here's my scenario.  My user wants to integrate my app with basecamp.  They click a link like: `http://myapp.com/api/basecamp/enable/abc123xyz`.  The `abc123xyz` in this case is the users id.  So my app then redirects to Basecamp to start the OAuth Process.

Once the user agrees to allow access, Basecamp redirects back to something like `http://myapp.com/api/basecamp/complete?code=123456`.  At this point the "chain" to the user is broken, so I don't know what user this code is for.  I tried using a redirect url of `http://myapp.com/api/basecamp/complete/abc123xyz` however basecamp rejects this URL as invalid, I'm assuming this is due to the redirect uri provided in the request not matching my registered app redirect url.

Any idea how I can pass something to github that they will pass back to me so I can associate the access token with the user requesting it be enabled?  Github allows for a `state` property to be sent during oauth requests that are tied to a user and sent back with their requests so the user can be looked up in between request.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after actually reading the docs, basecamp does support the state parameter, and with this my problem is solved.